# How can I display the results of my search form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I made a simple search form, that is basically searching through a couple of names on some items. I want to display the results on a new page, if the search query can be found in the name. I think it's really simple, just new to rails.

post_controler.rb -

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @posts = Post.all
  if params[:search]
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
end
```

routes.rb -

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/index' => 'posts#index'
  resources :post, :posts
end
```

application.html.erb -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Trial</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "defaults", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

index.html.erb -

```
    <html>
        <body>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <%= form_tag(posts_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
                    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Posts", class: 'form-control' %>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                     <%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
                </span>
                <% end %>
                </div>
                </form>

</body>
</html>
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
def self.search(search)
  where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%") 
end

end
```

Comment: Iterate over `@posts`. And don't select all of them if you don't need them, otherwise you're going to the DB twice. A tutorial might be in order, though, before going too much further.

Comment: kinda confused how to go about that besides

<%= posts.each do |p| %>

Comment: What's wrong with that? (But you don't want the `<%= ...`, you just want `<% ...` otherwise you'll get the string representation of the `each` return value, almost certainly not what you want.)

Comment: Do I just place this in the index file if I want it to create a new page to display the results?

Comment: You would if you want it on the resource's index page, yes. (That isn't a "new page", it's an existing page you're modifying.)

Comment: you could create a partial in `views/posts/` called `_post.html.erb` and design it the way you want each post displayed. The just add `<%= render @posts %>` and a little rails magic iterates over this passing in `post` each time.

Comment: Sorry, think I'm a little lost. I'm trying to have it open a new page after I click search, and from there display the items that match the search query.

Comment: @AlexanderTekle Then putting it in `index` wouldn't make any sense. You'd probably want a new action. Seriously--you'd be better served by spinning through a tutorial or two rather than trying to cobble something together based on SO comments/questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in your index.html.erb file. It doesn't matter whether there is search parameter or not. Just put the following code below your form.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <p>
    <%= post.name %>
  </p> 
<% end %>
```

Your controller code is fine. But doing the following will make it efficient. It will access database once.

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
  @posts = @posts.search(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
end
```

**Updated for redirecting to new page**

> post_controller.rb

```
def search
  @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
  @posts = @posts.search(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
end
```

> routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    post :search
  end
end
```

> search.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <p>
    <%= post.name %>
  </p> 
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps you. And in the form_tag of index.html.erb change the path to search.

Comment: How can I make it so that the results show up in a new page?

Comment: That is simple. Just put the url of the form to a new action, say for example search. Mention it in the routes a member. And have a new page for search action.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused on MVC still.

So how do I approach that? Do define a new action in my posts controller, and create a route to access that action? How do I make it so that it opens the new page for the results from there?

Comment: Where do you get "Member" from in the routes?

Comment: You are not limited to the seven routes that RESTful routing creates by default. If you like, you may add additional routes that apply to the 'Collection' or individual 'Members' of the collection. You can get details from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions